# window.clipboardData undefined in Microsoft Edge

Tags: angular, clipboard, microsoft-edge

I am trying to allow users to copy data from a data grid from the browser. This does not work in Microsoft Edge. It seems that _window.clipboardData return undefined when I print it in Microsoft Edge.

I had print statements reveal that window.navigator.clipboard and _window.clipboardData are both undefined. Why does _window.clipboardData return undefined?

I used _window because with window.clipboardData, I get this error:
Property 'clipboardData' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts

```
copyData(event: KeyboardEvent){
/*OTHER CODE*/
  if (window.navigator.clipboard) {
    windowNavigator.clipboard.writeText(data);
  } else {
    data = data.substring(0, data.length-1); //remove newline for Edge andIE
    const _window = window;
    _window.clipboardData.setData("text", data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Based on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData) clipboardData is a property of the event, not window as the error has said.

Comment: @Phix that block of code works in Internet Explorer, Chrome, and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `event.clipboardData`, instead of `window.clipboardData`, please refer to the following code:

Code in the html page:

```
<div class="source"  (copy)="oncopyData($event)" contenteditable="true">Try copying text from this box...</div>
<div class="target" (paste)="onPaste($event)" contenteditable="true">...and pasting it into this one</div>
```

Code in the component.ts file:

```
  oncopyData(event: ClipboardEvent){
    const selection = document.getSelection();
    event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', "Copy function: " + selection.toString().toUpperCase() );
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  onPaste(event:ClipboardEvent){
    let paste = (event.clipboardData).getData('text');
    paste = "Paste function: "+paste.toUpperCase();

    const selection = window.getSelection();
    if (!selection.rangeCount) return false;
    selection.deleteFromDocument();
    selection.getRangeAt(0).insertNode(document.createTextNode(paste));

    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

The result as below (using Microsoft Edge 44.18362 version):

[image]